# generate Dynamic Checkbox in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

plz tell me whats wrong in code bcz i m not able to add control on page. i m getting the values right & if i just `CheckBoxList2.Items.Add(row["subj_nme"].ToString());` the check box get created

```
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    chkList1 = new CheckBox();
                    chkList1.Text = row["subj_nme"].ToString();
                    chkList1.ID = row["subjid"].ToString();
                    chkList1.Checked = true;
                    chkList1.Font.Name = "Verdana";
                    chkList1.Font.Size = 12;
                    CheckBoxList2.Controls.Add(chkList1);
                }
            }
```

Comment: in which event are you creating this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use this code for binding your `CheckBoxList2` to DataTable as follow.

```
CheckBoxList2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
CheckBoxList2.DataTextField = "subj_nme";
CheckBoxList2.DataValueField = "subjid";
CheckBoxList2.DataBind();
CheckBoxList2.Font.Name = "Verdana";
CheckBoxList2.Font.Size = 12;
```

To check them all you can do this

```
for(int i=0;i<CheckBoxList2.Items.Count;i++)
{
CheckBoxList2.Items[i].Selected = true;
}
```